# Blob not available in the bucket for more than 15 seconds after upload is finished

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a **Multi-Regional** *EU (multiple regions in European Union)* bucket. Our customers upload files through our web interface using signed URLs. Once the upload is finished, a message gets published in a topic which triggers the execution of our thumbnail generation running in Cloud Run. For accessing the files I am using the *google-cloud-storage==1.14* Python library as follows:

```py
client = Client.from_service_account_json(config.GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
bucket = client.get_bucket(data_object.gcs_bucket_name)
bucket.get_blob(data_object.gcs_object_name)
```

It happens very often (for ~20% of the uploaded files), especially if the files are uploaded by customers from the United States, that `bucket.get_blob(..)` returns `None`. For this reason the thumbnail generation fails. I have already built in a 15 seconds delay, but some of the images are still not getting processed.

I really only publish the message which kicks off the processing after the `PUT` request returns, but it looks as if there was some kind of a replication delay or similar and the uploaded files were not available right after the upload.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: how much those files usually weights?

Comment: From 1MB up to 100MB. But it has just happened today that a customer uploaded around 80 files at once which were around 1MB each. Some did not get processed because of the problem described above.

Comment: @Chris32 Do you have any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: I would have to reproduce this uploading from a no gcp computer from USA to reproduce this, but why aren't you just using a Cloud Function triggered by the upload event? Do you have any special requirement? I have a similar setup on a personal application where I upload files from the web and the thumbnails are being autogenerated by Cloud Functions

Comment: @Chris32 Thank you for your answer. Yes, that is a possible alternative to try, however, I have an entry in our SQL database for every blob, tracking the state of the upload as well (`INIT`, `UPLOAD_COMPLETED`, `PROCESSING`, `COMPLETED`). Right now the state change is the trigger for the processing. I would like to be in full control of the trigger. Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency) the object should be immediately available for download once I receive a success response, so in theory there should not be a difference.